# I need to publish website using git-pages but not on sub branch created from master eg staging

Tags: github

To publish my website on branch other than master in GitHUb

I had created a branch called staging from master branch and I want to publish that branch rather than master for my code  and will publish on master when the testing is done .

If there any way to publish on branch for testing and merge the code to master branch as final deployment.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi there, please look at this guide [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

The help page "[Configuring a publishing source for GitHub Pages](https://help.github.com/en/articles/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-github-pages)" is clear:

> You can configure GitHub Pages to publish your site's source files from `master`, `gh-pages`, or a `/docs` folder on your `master` branch for Project Pages and other Pages sites that meet certain criteria.
>
> If your site is a User or Organization Page that has a repository named <`username>.github.io` or `<orgname>.github.io`, you cannot publish your site's source files from different locations.
> [User and Organization Pages](https://help.github.com/en/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages) that have this type of repository name are only published from the `master` branch.

You have [various tricks to publish from a subfolder](https://gist.github.com/cobyism/4730490#gistcomment-2337463), or [another folder](https://musteresel.github.io/posts/2018/01/git-worktree-for-deploying.html), but not from other branches.